# Calculating a sum indexed by $t|gcd(m,n)$

Tags: summation, number-theory

I would like to know how to implement the sum $$f(m,n)=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{t|gcd(m,n)}{\frac{m}{t}+\frac{n}{t}-1 \choose \frac{m}{t}}\phi(t)\right)$$
for two given positive entires $m, n$. Here, $\phi$ is Euler's totient function and the thing between parentheses is the binomial notation. My difficulty is to define the sum of all the parcels ${\frac{m}{t}+\frac{n}{t}-1 \choose \frac{m}{t}}\phi(t)$ such that $t$ divides $gcd(m,n)$. I guess there is a simple solution for that.

Comment: Mulitply the summand by `Boole[Mod[GCD[m,n],t]==0]`?

Comment: @kglr yeah that's a good solution... thank you =)

Comment: out of curiosity, are these the  circular binomial coefficients?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform nope :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sum[..., {t,Divisors[GCD[m,n]]}]
```

Comment: thats a pretty solution. It's true that Sum accepts successive values as one can see here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html